# Is it possible to set Load Balancing to access the resource outside GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to set Load Balancing to access the resource outside GCP?

We want to set Load Balance to access either GCP resource or our
on-premises servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not yet.

I've starred this question to update it when such functionality will become available.